# How to add multiple files in this same batch line

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

This code is used to remove all files and folders from the c:\test directory except "FolderA"

```
@echo off
pushd "C:\test" || exit /B 1
for /D %%D in ("*") do (
    if /I not "%%~nxD"== "FolderA" rd /S /Q "%%~D"
)
for %%F in ("*") do (
    del "%%~F"
)
popd
```

In case I want to omit more than one folder, how could I add it? i mean delete everything except FolderA FolderB and Folder C (Names can contain spaces)

this doesn't work

```
@echo off
pushd "C:\test" || exit /B 1
for /D %%D in ("*") do (
    if /I not "%%~nxD"== "FolderA" "FolderB" "Folder C" rd /S /Q "%%~D"
)
for %%F in ("*") do (
    del "%%~F"
)
popd
```

Comment: One option is using the findstr command with conditional execution. `echo %%D |findstr /v /i "FolderA FolderB FolderC" 2>nul && rd /s /q "%%D"` You could also put all the folder names in a file and use the `/G` option.

Comment: would your folders possibly contain whitespace at all?

Comment: That's right, at least two of them contain spaces

Comment: Since this does not distinguish between a directory and file name, a file named "FolderA" would also not be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can produce a logical AND if you write if-clauses in a row:

```
if /I not "%%~nxD" == "FolderA" if /I not "%%~nxD" == "FolderB" if /I not "%%~nxD" == "FolderC" rd /S /Q "%%~D"
```

Comment: Kind of a brute force option that becomes untenable when more and more folders need to be excluded.

Answer (score 1):

For a few items I would probably use this code:

```cmd
@echo off
pushd "C:\test" || exit /B 1
for /D %%D in ("*") do (
    set "ITEM=%%~nxD"
    cmd /V /D /C echo(!ITEM!| findstr /V /X /I /C:"FolderA" /C:"FolderB" /C:"Folder C" 2> nul && rd /S /Q "%%~D"
)
for %%F in ("*") do (
    del "%%~F"
)
popd
```

---

For numerous items I would put their names into a text file, a name per line, say `exclude.txt`:

> ```cmd
> FolderA
> FolderB
> Folder C
> ```

and then I would use this code:

```cmd
@echo off
pushd "C:\test" || exit /B 1
for /D %%D in ("*") do (
    set "ITEM=%%~nxD"
cmd /V /D /C echo(!ITEM!| findstr /V /X /I /L /G:"exclude.txt" 2> nul && rd /S /Q "%%~D"
)
for %%F in ("*") do (
    del "%%~F"
)
popd
```

---

If you want to avoid slow pipes `|`, you could also use the following `for` loop approach, which avoids long `if` chains like `if /I not "%%~nxD"=="FolderA" if /I not "%%~nxD"=="FolderB" if /I not "%%~nxD"=="Folder C" …`:

```cmd
@echo off
pushd "C:\test" || exit /B 1
for /D %%D in ("*") do (
    set "FLAG=#"
    for %%I in ("FolderA" "FolderB" "Folder C") do (
        if /I "%%~nxD"=="%%~I" set "FLAG="
    )
    if defined FLAG rd /S /Q "%%~D"
)
for %%F in ("*") do (
    del "%%~F"
)
popd
```